# Append text to each row of the sql select query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) 'Records Affected', TYPE FROM MASTER
GROUP BY TYPE
```

The output for this is

```
Records Affected            TYPE
----------------            ---- 
4                            F1
3                            F2
5                            F3
```

Now I would like to change the query so that the output will be as follows

```
Records Affected
----------------
The number of records affected for F1 is : 4 
The number of records affected for F2 is : 3
The number of records affected for F3 is : 5

"The number of records affected for " + TYPE + " is : " + COUNT.
```

How can I add the default text to each row of the result set instead of appending in the front end. I would like to simplify my task of just showing the records in the DataGrid as Summary.

Comment: What is the `C#` part of the question?

Comment: I just want to show the output in the DataGrid as it is... instead of altering the DataSet and binding it to DataGrid. I want to just simplify my ouput in the backend.

Comment: Just my opinion here - while you could do this with the given answers, you'd be better off getting the raw data from the database and building your message in your app code (either code or your grid markup). This type of message is part of your user experience, not part of your data, so it belongs in your user experience code. This will also give you the opportunity to change your message later, localize it, reformat it, export it, etc., without having to touch your data access layer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can easily concatenate the string using the following.  You will use the `+` to concatenate the string to the `type` column and the `count`. Note, the `count` needs to be converted to a `varchar` for this to work:

```
SELECT 
  'The number of records affected for '+ type +
    ' is : '+ cast(COUNT(ID) as varchar(50)) as'Records Affected'
FROM yt
GROUP BY TYPE;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/817e1/4)

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however my concatenation added spaces before the added text was added. One of my results might return "data           The number of rows affected for" instead of there only being one space added. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Never mind. This only happens when using SQL Server Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the text in your query:

```
SELECT 'The number of records affected for ' + TYPE + ' is : ' + CAST(COUNT(ID) as VARCHAR(20)) AS 'Records Affected' FROM MASTER
GROUP BY TYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT "The number of records affected for " + TYPE + " is : " + COUNT(ID) AS [Records Affected]
FROM Master 
GROUP BY TYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
UPDATE bookmark_linx SET link_url=(SELECT CONCAT(link_url, '?raw=true')) WHERE link_url LIKE '%dropbox%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 'The number of records affected for ' + TYPE + ' is : ' + 
STR(X.[Records Affected]) AS [Records Affected]
FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) 'Records Affected', TYPE FROM MASTER GROUP BY TYPE) X
```